# Trouble selecting/creating Partition 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install 14.04.3 LTS along side Windows 10 until I get the hang on Linux (this is my first experience with Linux).

I'm using a DVD to install, which has created a dual boot option when I start my Presario CQ57 laptop up.

I'm following the instructions listed here - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop (Step 4 doesn't give the option of installing alongside another OS, so I selected 'something else').

I created a partition in Windows 10 in the disk managment and allocated space for 14.04.3 (211GB) and was a ntfs.

Everything seems to work in the installation process up to the point where I have to select the partition and create a root etc. - It doesn't seem to recognise and/ or list the partition I created in Windows 10 disk management (or at least I'm not sure if it does). The listed choices are:

- /dev/sda
- /dev/sda1      1MB Windows 7 (loader)
- /dev/sda2 ntfs 208MB Windows 7 (loader)
- /dev/sda3 ntfs 258328MB     - This looks like the amount space remaining in the drive after I created the partition
- /dev/sda4 ntfs  241568MB (12304MB used) Windows 7 Recovery Environment (loader) - The used space in this option looks like the same amount of space used in the partition I created.

I have no idea which one of these above I should or shouldn't attempt to use

"New Partition" doesn't hilight to click on any except on /dev/sda, and if I do that, I get a warning saying it will wipe everything.

So, can anyone tell me what I need to do here, or which Partition I need to use to continue the installation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Boot from Ubuntu install media.
- Select <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>.
- Open <kbd>GParted</kbd> (Partitioning tool).
- Check if you find sufficient unallocated space.
- If yes - create a new partition and format it with ext4 (size that fits your needs).
- Then create another one and format it with swap (size minimun matching RAM).
- If not - reduce the Windows partition.
- Create a partition for Ubuntu (size that fits your needs).
- Create a swap partition (size minimum matching RAM).
- On the desktop click <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd>.
- Choose <kbd>Something else</kbd>.
- Select the partition you created for Ubuntu before.

Hint : Before that disable hibernation and Fast Boot in Windows - then shutdown (NOT reboot).